# Glassfish 4 JBDCRealm NameNotFoundException

Tags: java, security, glassfish, jdbcrealm

This might be very basic, but I stuck in it for couple of hours now, so please hear me out.

I'm trying to do a JDBCRealm-based of authentication in a Java 7 web app on Glassfish 4.0 in Eclipse. This blog [post](http://blog.eisele.net/2013/01/jdbc-realm-glassfish312-primefaces342.html) was the reference for cofiguring JDBCRealm.

web.xml is as follow

```
<login-config>
  <auth-method>FORM</auth-method>
  <realm-name>MyJDBCRealm</realm-name>
  <form-login-config>
    <form-login-page>/login.html</form-login-page>
    <form-error-page>/tologin.html</form-error-page>
  </form-login-config>
</login-config>
```

When I start the Glassfish server it's clearly written in console that:

```
SEC1115: Realm [MyJDBCRealm] of classtype [com.sun.enterprise.security.ee.auth.realm.jdbc.JDBCRealm] successfully created.
```

But when I request any app's resource, I'm getting this exception

```
javax.naming.NamingException: Lookup failed for 'MyJDBCRealm' in SerialContext[myEnv={java.naming.factory.initial=com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialInitContextFactory, java.naming.factory.state=com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.JNDIStateFactoryImpl, java.naming.factory.url.pkgs=com.sun.enterprise.naming} [Root exception is javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: MyJDBCRealm not found]
```

with root cause:

```
javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: MyJDBCRealm not found
  at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.TransientContext.doLookup(TransientContext.java:237)
  at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.TransientContext.lookup(TransientContext.java:204)
  ...
```

which happens here

```
public DataSource getDataSource() {
  DataSource datasource = null;

  try {
    datasource = (DataSource) initialContext.lookup("MyJDBCRealm");
  } catch (NamingException ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
  }

  return datasource;
}
```

I should note that the Hibernate successfully connects to backend database and maps the tables and in the glassfish console, I can successfully ping the JDBC connection pool.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you are confusing something.

A realm is not the same thing as a datasource. To get an instance of a realm in Java you can do the following:

```
JDBCRealm realm = (JDBCRealm) Realm.getInstance("realmName");
```

If you really want to get a datasource you have to use JNDI name which often starts with `jdbc/` like this:

```
DataSource datasource = (DataSource) initialContext.lookup("jdbc/MyJDBCRealm");
```

But anyway I think for normal JDBC based authentication you don't need something like this.